# How to get AJAX Progress for an POST request?

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, ajax, flask

I'm making an AJAX HTTP POST request to an Python flask REST api. Can I get the percentage of the request completed?

Any suggestion using `$ajax` or `$http`?

I have tried the below code. I'm getting the values along with the response.

```
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    console.log(percentComplete * 100);
     $('.progress').css({
           width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
     });
     if (percentComplete == 1) {
         $('.progress').addClass('hide');
     }
}
}, false);
return xhr;
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Note that you can only get the progress of the request *being sent*, not the progress of data being processed on the server or returned. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: It's best to use `$http` in AngularJS applications. `$http` has `uploadEventHandlers` in config that will notify your progress.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I'm not uploading any file, just a JSON POST & JSON response

Comment: @Mr.Developer I have edited my question by adding the code I have tried

Comment: @Krishna there is also `eventHandlers` [check the config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage). jQuery is usually not used since it's not part of angularjs's $digest cycle